# Why AWS Ubuntu server showing extra Drive size

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04

When I created Ubuntu machine (ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-20150325 (ami-d85e75b0)) in AWS, Why it is showing extra drive space by default? I have created with 8GB, but it is shoing extra 1 GB. Please find the attched image.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxblW.png)

Thanks,
D Naveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only device you need to be concerned with is `/dev/xvda1` - the rest of the devices in the output are Linux system devices.